# SQL Server Indexed View syntax for joined DB

Tags: sql-server, indexing, view

I'm trying to set up an index on a VIEW of mine.
First error was 1939, Schema Binding required.

Ok, no problem with that.

```
ALTER VIEW xyz WITH SCHEMABINDING AS abc
```

Now, in this VIEW I'm using one local table
[dbo].][ReleantTable] and two joined tables
from other databases on the same server:

OtherDbName..OtherRelevantTable

Altering the VIEW fails, stating OtherDbName..OtherRelevantTable
is invalid for schema binding.

I guess it's just an syntax issue. Could anyone get me hint
how to address my OtherDb?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to create an indexed view your base tables must reside within the same database.

Consult the following Microsoft Books Online reference for further details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432(SQL.90).aspx

Comment: thx for the answer. actually i need that index desperatly for performance reasons. is there any way to get a single field of that view indexed eventough it collects data from other 'places' too?

Comment: @KB22: To answer your further query, unfortunately the answer is no. You see in order to create say a non clustered index on a view you first must create a Clustered Index. In order to do this SQL Server has to physically materialise the table data from the view and in doing so must validate the full contents of the view. This action cannot be performed when a view contains base tables that are distributed across separate databases.

Comment: Further to my previous comments, I would suggest a good starting point would be to construct the cross database query that would satisfy your selection requirements and then review the execution plan. Ensure all your join predicates and search arguments have suitable indexes in place etc.

Comment: @John: thx for the elaborate answer. I read more into it and solved the problem with a 'pre-located table' which contains the relevant data physically in the relevant database. Anyways, some more lessons learned. ;)

  k